# how to keep the unfiltered data in the collection in Java 8 Streaming API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

My Input Sequence is : `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Result should be : `[1,12,3,14,5]`

That is even numbers are incremented by 10, but odd values are left intact.

Here is what I tried:

```
public static List<Integer> incrementEvenNumbers(List<Integer> arrays){
        List<Integer> temp = 
          arrays.stream()
                .filter(x->x%2==0)
                .map(i -> i+10)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return temp;
    }
```

when I call this method,

```
System.out.println(incrementEvenNumbers(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)));
```

I get `[12, 14]`. I am wondering how to include the values not `filtered` to seep in but the `map` should not be applied for it.

Comment: The `filter(Predicate)` function will always kick out the values which the predicate rejects; so as long as you're using a filter the odd numbers will disappear. Of course there are methods to achieve what you want as you can see in Alexis' answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator with `map`, so that the function you apply is either the identity for odd values, or the one that increments the value by 10 for even values:

```
 List<Integer> temp = arrays.stream()
                            .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i+10 : i)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem, as you saw, is that filter will remove the elements so when a terminal operation will be called, they will be filtered by the predicate.

Note that if you don't care modifying the list in place, you can use `replaceAll` directly, as you are doing a mapping from a type T to T.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
list.replaceAll(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i+10 : i); //[1, 12, 3, 14, 5]
```

Comment: nice approach, did not think about it!

Comment: I have complex problem ( I simplified here for just odd values). I have a List of Objects on which I have to modify certain objects and return the entire list with modified and unmodified objects. I suppose I can pass a predicate to the map ternary..

Comment: `map()` takes a `Function` as parameter but yes. You would likely use a method reference if the logic is complex.